# Google Calendar API sending event data to Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a workflow using Google Calendar, Pub/Sub Topics, and a Subscriber.

The process would be as follows:

1. when an event is created on a particular calendar on Google Calendar, the Calendar API adds the event metadata (start date/time, end date/time, etc.) to a topic.
2. The Pub/Sub subscription then calls the subscriber (a Google Cloud Function) and passes the topic data
3. The Google Cloud function executes while using the data it got from the topic (calendar event info)/

Part 2 and 3 seems to be the easy bit, I am able to create a topic (which has an endpoint) and I'm able to create the subscription which will have my Cloud Function's endpoint configured to be the subscription.

Part 1 is what I'm struggling to understand. Can anyone please tell me how to configure Google Calendar so when a certain calendar gets updated with a new event, the api sends that new event's info to the topic configured to the pub/sub topic?

Any help with this would be extremely appreciated!

Many Thanks,

Dean

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push) you can get event updates only through http(s) webhooks.

In your case you must have some http service that receives requests to webhook endpoint and publishes to Google PubSub channel.